# [Chrome Devtools Protocol]: Get Renderer Process ID through Devtools Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

### Problem Description

I am trying to get chromium renderer process id of chrome relative to specific tab(page, frame) using Devtools Protocol. I know there has chrome api[1] `chrome.processes` for doing such things(eg. `chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab`). However, I wonder if any equivalent api in Devtools Protocol[2] doing the things too. I can't find explicit solution in Devtools document[2].

Thanks for your help.

### Reference

[1] “chrome.processes,” Chrome Developers. [Online]. Available: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes. [Accessed: 14-Jun-2021].

[2] "Chrome DevTools Protocol," Chrome Developers. [Online]. Available: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/. [Accessed: 14-Jun-2021]

Comment: I would like to be able to do this too.  The devtools/browser/ID endpoint gives process IDs but there doesn't seem to be a way to map it back to a specific tab.